# Divergence of the sequence $\{\frac{e^n}{2^n+1}\}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

While studying sequences I came across $a_n= \frac{e^n}{2^n+1}$ which is divergent according to the answer key.

Attempting to take the limit results in $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{e^n/2^n}{1+1/2^n}$.

Am I correct in thinking that the reason it is divergent is because $e^n$ grows significantly faster than $2^n$ as $n$ goes to infinity?

Is the same applicable for any  ${c^n}/{d^n}$ where $c>d$ and both positive?

Comment: If $c>d$ then $(c/d)^n = (1+a)^n$ with $a>0$ and $(1+a)^n > 1 + na $ by Bernoulli's inequality

Comment: It diverges because 1 < e/2.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are familiar with the following fact: If $r>1$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} r^n = \infty$$

From here, a simple comparison is enough:

$$\dfrac{e^n}{2^n+1} > \dfrac{e^n}{2^n+2^n} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot\left(\dfrac{e}{2}\right)^n$$

Comment: That's a very clean way to prove it, thank you. My original thoughts are also correct though, no?

Comment: Your thoughts are, if c,d are positive which is equivalent to $r>1$